# Repeat message in Mouse Proc C++ Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, mouse-hook

I have a procedure that when a user press Ctrl button and right click it will show a message box to screen. But it has a loop, I only press Ctrl button and right click once time but it shows a sequence of message box. How to fix this?
https://youtu.be/LzI9M_zEEKQ

This is my MouseProc procedure

```
    #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    unsigned char  KeyState[256];

    LRESULT EXPORT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (nCode < 0)
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        GetKeyboardState(KeyState);

        if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
        {
            if ((wParam == WM_RBUTTONUP) && (KeyState[VK_CONTROL] & 0x80))
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, L"Ctrl + Right Click", L"Mouse hook", MB_OK);
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It appears that your hook procedure receives a new message, when you dismiss the message box with the mouse. Do you see the same effect, when dismissing the message box with the keyboard? It's generally a bad idea to place a blocking UI in a hook procedure. If you want to test your code in a less intrusive way, use [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) in place of your `MessageBox` call.

Comment: It still appear when I dismiss the message box with the enter button.

Comment: That message box repeats exactly 30 times.

Comment: You are not getting the message.  Stop using MessageBox, use OutputDebugString instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shall not use `MessageBox()` in message hooks as it breaks normal message hook flow - MessageBox() runs its own modal loop.

If you need exactly `MessageBox` there then you should use `PostMessage` with custom message and handler. In this case MessageBox will be invoked after `CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);`

Comment: Thank you! I will try again!